# animate nav bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can the following script can be adjusted to animate the height of the nav, currently it pause then jumps from one size to another, im aware of the animate function in jQuery but just usure how and where to implement it here. Also the script is calculating the height of the nav as a quarter of the width.

```
$(function() {
var pause = 200; // will only process code within delay(function() { ... }) every 100ms.

$(window).resize(function() {

    delay(function() {


        var width = $(window).width();

        if( width >= 600 ) {
            // code for tablet view


                var cw = $('nav a').width()/4; // calculation here
                $('nav, nav ul, nav a').css({'height':cw+'px'}) // target
                $('nav, nav ul, nav a').css({'line-height':cw+'px'}) //   target


        } else if( width <= 600 ) {
            // code for mobile portrait

                var cw = $('nav a').width()/4; // calculation here
                $('nav, nav ul, nav a').css({'height':cw+'px'}) // target
                $('nav, nav ul, nav a').css({'line-height':cw+'px'}) //      target
        }

    }, pause );

});

$(window).resize();

});
```

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `.css` to `.animate`. jQuery's animate function animates smoothly between different css values for things like margin and height. Other arguments can be provided for things like changing the duration of the animation. Full documentation can be found [here.](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Not all properties can be animated with the jQuery `.animate` command, so at times it may take some work to figure out how to style your document in a way that makes it possible to animate it how you want.